# Trying to use Google Speech to Text in Android => UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials should use fail() instead of throwing exceptions

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

Hi all I'm trying to transcribe an audio file with Google's Speech-to-Text API and ive had alot of trouble. Right now it's reporting this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauteenticatedException:io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:

UNAUTHENTICATED: Credentials should use fail() instead of throwing exceptions
```

Im using `speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync()` to get a transcription from an audio file that is stored in device storage. I should be getting a response in about 30s but instead it runs for ~2 mins and prints the error above.

Here is where i pass the credentials and initialize the speech client:

```
private var speechClient: SpeechClient? = null
private var grpcStub: GrpcSpeechStub? = null


// initiate speech client after service connected
private fun initSpeechClient(){
    if(speechClient == null) {

        // Configure polling algorithm
        val speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
        val timedRetryAlgorithm: TimedRetryAlgorithm = OperationTimedPollAlgorithm.create(
            RetrySettings.newBuilder()
                .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(500L))
                .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
                .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
                .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(1.0) // ignored
                .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
                .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofHours(24L)) // set polling timeout to 24 hours
                .build()
        )
        SpeechStubSettings.newBuilder()?.apply {
            credentialsProvider = SpeechCredentialsProvider(context!!.applicationContext)
            speechSettings.longRunningRecognizeOperationSettings().pollingAlgorithm =
                timedRetryAlgorithm
            grpcStub = GrpcSpeechStub.create(build())
        }
        speechClient = SpeechClient.create(grpcStub)
    }
}
```

In the code below, the error is also clocked at some point in the error message as coming from val results = response.get().resultsList.

I can provide more insight if needed. Thanks :)

```
package com.example.gptbros.utils

import com.example.gptbros.model.api.TranscriptItem
import com.example.gptbros.ui.home.HomeViewModel
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
class TranscriptAPI(
    var byteString: ByteString,
    var speechClient: SpeechClient
) {
    suspend fun fetchTranscript(): TranscriptItem {
        // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        speechClient.use { speech ->

            // Configure remote file request for FLAC
            val config =
                RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC)
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .build()
            val audio =
                RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUriBytes(
                    byteString
                ).build()

            // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
            val response =
                speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio)
            while (!response.isDone) {
                println("Waiting for response...")
                delay(10000)
            }
            val results =
                response.get().resultsList

            // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
            // first (most likely) one here.
            val alternative =
                results[0].alternativesList[0]
            return TranscriptItem(alternative.transcript, alternative.confidence)
        }

    }
}
```